# How to remove ticks?

Tags: plotting, options, visualization, ticks

I wanted to remove the `Ticks` in my coding but i can't. Here when i try to remove the `Ticks` the number also gone. I need numbers without `Ticks`, `Ticks` and `GridLines`   should be automatic and don't use`PlotRange` .

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, ImageSize -> 400, BarOrigin -> Left, 
          ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ImageSize -> {500, 300}, 
          GridLines -> {Automatic, None}, Ticks -> {{Automatic}, None}
          , 
          LabelStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1]], 
          TicksStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.3]]
          , 
          Axes -> {True, False}, AxesStyle -> Opacity[.0], 
          ChartStyle -> {RGBColor[.06, .29, .66], RGBColor[.01, .56, .61], 
                         RGBColor[1, .58, 0]},
          ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[GrayLevel[.6]]]
```

[image]

Comment: [Removing ticks.](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/139/133) :o)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard http://www.cdc.gov/ticks/removing_a_tick.html   ...if only the removal of bug were that simple.

Comment: niren, please consider [Accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/158428) answers to some of your questions.

Answer (score 11):

Simply use option:

```
TicksStyle -> Directive[20, Opacity[0], FontOpacity -> 0.3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Credit to [R.M](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/rm-rf) for showing me `FontOpacity`.

Answer (score 4):

You could specify the `Ticks` manually, for example by

```
Ticks -> {Table[{i, i, 0}, {i, 0, 14, 2}], None},
```

The y axis stays without Ticks by the `None` the x axis gets at $i=0,2,...,14$ a Tick at $i$ with $i$ as label and zero ticks width.

Comment: No Ticks should be used because when i change value of `BarChart` the number have to change automatically based on values.

Comment: You could adapt the `Table`to the values the `Ticks` should be based on. E.g. if you have a `min` and a `max` and want to have `num` values `Table[{i,i,0},{i,min,max,(max-min)/num}]`

Comment: Though I haven't had the possibility to check that here you may want to look at the `CutomTicks` package or this `TickControl` Code http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5217

Answer (score 4):

You can keep the numbers as they current show up but remove the ticks by specifying ticks as follows:

```
Ticks -> {Table[{2 i, 2 i, 0}, {i, 7}], None}
```

or

```
Ticks -> {Table[{2 i + 1, 2 i + 1, 0}, {i, 0, 8}], None}
```

(each tick is specified by a triplet {a,b,c}, with a corresponding to the location on the axis, b the label used, and c the length of the tick used - just set the length equal to 0).

Answer (score 2):

Due to `AbsoluteOptions` reporting `Ticks` and `GridLines` in an unuseable fashion, I've had to resort to `Rasterizing` to find out how many grid lines are automatically being produced.

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

bc = BarChart[data, ImageSize -> 400, BarOrigin -> Left, 
   ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ImageSize -> {500, 300}, 
   GridLines -> {Automatic, None}, Ticks -> {{Automatic}, None}, 
   LabelStyle -> 
    Directive[Bold, Opacity[1], Thick, Black, 
     FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
   TicksStyle -> Directive[20, Opacity[.3]], Axes -> {True, False}, 
   AxesStyle -> Opacity[.0], 
   ChartStyle -> {RGBColor[.06, .29, .66], RGBColor[.01, .56, .61], 
     RGBColor[1, .58, 0]}, ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[GrayLevel[.6]]];

rbc = Rasterize[bc];
lines = Min[Last /@ Tally[rbc[[1, 1, -1]](* Top row of pixels *)]];
max = Max[Total /@ data];
interval = Quotient[max, (lines - 1)];
maxline = (lines - 1)*interval;
ticks = {Table[{i,(* Frame for padding *)Framed[ToString[i],
  FrameStyle -> None], 0}, {i, 0, maxline, interval}], None};

BarChart[data, ImageSize -> 400, BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ImageSize -> {500, 300}, 
 GridLines -> {Automatic, None}, Ticks -> ticks, 
 LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[Bold, Opacity[1], Thick, Black, 
   FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[20, Opacity[.3]], Axes -> {True, False}, 
 AxesStyle -> Opacity[.0], 
 ChartStyle -> {RGBColor[.06, .29, .66], RGBColor[.01, .56, .61], 
   RGBColor[1, .58, 0]}, ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[GrayLevel[.6]]]
```

[image]