# Plots without axes labeling

Tags: plotting, labeling

I need to plot in Mathematica without labeling. For example, this code:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-2, 2}}]
```

produces this plot:

[image]

However, I need only figure and not the labeling of horizontal and vertical axis.

Comment: Related: [(16749)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16749/121) (converse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the tick marks, then how about this:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-2, 2}}, LabelStyle -> Opacity[0]]
```

[image: labels gone]

Here I used `LabelStyle` to make the labels transparent (even though they are still generated together with the ticks). Alternatively, you can manually specify the tick marks with empty labels, but I assume you want something that retains the automatic placement of the ticks.

**Another approach:**

There's also this method, using the `ImagePadding` option:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-2, 2}}, ImagePadding -> 1]
```

[image: labels gone]

What this does is to make the border around the frame defined by the `PlotRange` so thin that there isn't enough room to display any of the tick labels. I just have to make sure that there is enough padding to show the frame, that's why the value `0` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can (mis)use `FrameTicksStyle`:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-2, 2}}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0]]
```

[image]

Comment: It was also a helpful answer. thanks a lot

Comment: @zenith You're most welcome, thanks for the positive feedback!

Answer (score 3):

```
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-2, 2}},
 FrameTicksStyle -> {{{0.1}, None}, {0.1, None}}]
```

Comment: You're removing the labels AND the tick marks

Comment: no, i wanted to remove only labels.

Comment: Try running the code.

Comment: this code also produced desired results but i observed some extra dots. thanks for the help