# Removing ticks from a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, ticks

Let's consider the following simple example

```
Clear["Global`*"];
C0 = ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];
S0 = Show[{C0}, AxesStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BoxStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.005]], 
PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> 550]
```

[image]

Now I want the following: remove all ticks (and numbers) from all three axes, while keeping the labels $x$, $y$, and $z$. If it was a simple 2D plot I could use `FrameTicks -> None`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove ticks?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16749/how-to-remove-ticks)

Answer (score 3):

I just found that `Ticks -> None` simply does what I want!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adopting @Royce [suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16749/how-to-remove-ticks?rq=1) over here,

```
Ticks -> {Table[{2 i, 2 i, 0}, {i, 7}], None}
```

[image]

Comment: I used this trick in v9 but the ticks on the vertical axis remain unperturbed!

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I cannot confirm that coz I am using v11.